# jQuery if user active; reload div, stop reloading if user is inactive

Tags: jquery, load, timeout, python-idle

I have the following scenario.
My twitter feed should refresh every 5 seconds (by using the load() function). Although I have been monitoring my bandwidth and it really sucks up a lot.

My idea was to stop refreshing as soon as the user goes inactive (say, 5 or 10 seconds no interaction on the page). I tried a few plugins but without success.

The refreshing goes as follows:

```
setInterval(function() { $("#feed").load("feed.php"); }, 5000);
```

It should stop refresh, but the plugins I tried just kept refreshing (running the interval).

Is there any way to achieve this? I tried the following plugins:
 - http://www.bedroomlan.org/coding/detecting-‘idle’-and-‘away’-timeouts-javascript
 - http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My solution would be to change it from a 5-second refresh to something like 30 seconds, unless you're a genuine speed reader.

Comment: "Twitter: Because your ADD isn't severe enough."

Comment: This is used at an event. While being at the event, tons of people tweet. Sometimes more than 3 per 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `idleTimer` jQuery plugin.

- http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/

One of it's capabilities is to get the amount of time since the user was last active.  It allows you to write the following code.

```
setInterval(function () { 
  if ($.idleTimer('getElapsedTime') < 5000) {
    $("#feed").load("feed.php");
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. After I get inactive, it still keeps refreshing.

Comment: @Roel did you make sure to initialize the `idleTimer` with a value first. I believe that's required to use `getElapsedTime`

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thank you muchly!

Answer (score 1):

How about tracking where the mouse is?
Every 5 seconds or whenever, see if the mouse's coordinates are the same as they were in the previous check.  If they are the same, then presume the mouse did not move.  Don't refresh your feed then.  If they are different, refresh your feed.

Just a thought.